# jQuery .val() returning wrong

Tags: jquery, input, get

I have the following in a simple form;

```
<form method="post" action="inc/core.php">
    <input type="textbox" name="lognick" value="samp" />
    <input type="password" name="logpass" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to get their value through;

```
var logname = $("input[name=lognick]").val();
var logpass = $("input[name=logpass]").val();
```

logname always returns "samp" (the default value) and logpass undefined. I also tried using `.attr("value")` but it's the same outcome.

When trying to use it on a blank page it works flawlessly.
Here's the whole onclick function; http://pastebin.com/pQiVAuEW

Thanks!

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem?   http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Depending on your jQuery version, could you try `.prop('value')`?

Comment: Do you have more form elements with these names?

Comment: when you even did not add the value attribute, is it expected to get 'undefined' by val() or attr('value').

Comment: wrap name value by single quotes: var logpass = $("input[name='logpass']").val();

Comment: The logpass name used twice on this page. Try this: var logpass = $("input[name='logpass']").get(0).value;

Comment: Thank you OneHalfTrackMindMan! Using get(1) fixed it!!

Comment: It seems like the plugin bxSlider.js is wrapping the form, but persisting the old input elements - so you have each one twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate the problem and I am able to access the value fine. The password box has no value so it should be undefined.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefl/A7Bfr/).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `$('#some_id').val()` or `document.getElementById("some_id").value` ? If they don't work, are you calling the function in correct place? It can happen, that the code (JavaScript I suppose) is run in the writing phase of the form and not after you're typing the values.